# Freeswitch PJSIP client, PESQ score incorrect

Tags: voip, pjsip, freeswitch

I am trying to measure voice-quality (PESQ Score) by playing a file at server and recoding it at client-side and then passing both files to ITU implementation of PESQ score computation.

While the codec negotiated is PCMU(G.711) so I should get PESQ score of 4.1 (or something near that) but the score I am getting is in range of 3.4-3.7.

After computing score for more than 40 recordings PESQ Scores I am getting is:
AVG: 3.4278035714
MAX: 3.707
MIN: 3.343

**I don't understand what is it that I am doing incorrectly. Why am I not getting scores close to 4.1 ??**
**Setup:** 
File (PCM@8000) --- FreeSwitch(PCMU@8000) ---PJSIPClient(PCMU@8000)---File(PCM@8000)
Server and client are on same server.
Server: Freeswitch
Client: PJSUA Python client

**Audio file format (@Server):** RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 8000 Hz
**Audio file format (@cilent, recorded by client):** RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 8000 Hz
**Codec negotiated between client and server** is PCMU@8000h

> t=0 0
>   m=audio 28734 RTP/AVP 0 96
>   a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
>   a=rtpmap:96 telephone-event/8000
>   a=fmtp:96 0-16
>   a=ptime:20
>   a=rtcp:28735 IN IP4 192.168.1.236

Comment: did you actually listen to the recorded audio? Maybe there are distortions that lowered the score? Also make sure that you insert silent pauses at the start and the end of the playback, so that the original audio is not cut off. Also use Audacity to look at the waves and compare. The PESQ tool is quite reliable, I played with it a lot.

Comment: You can easily find my contacts. Let's talk and discuss the issue.

Comment: Thanx StanislavSinyagin your suggestions helped me getting more relevant scores but there are still some irregularities that i am not able to understand.

Comment: Come out to skype or Google hangouts during the week, let's look at the problem in details.